# simple captcha problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, captcha

i am using 'jquery simple captcha' plugin on some of my forms. but after tries it more that 10 times to submit the form,it accept the wrong selected image.

why is it so??

Comment: @Hd I'm afraid we will need more info that that.

Comment: @hd I hate to say this, but the obvious answer is that you are a robot.

Comment: @Spiny Norman: oh my God.i am not a robot.why do you say it? i am just trying to develop a nice and secure form for my site.

Comment: @Pino: i think i have found the problem.maybe it is because of session problem on my site.i will try to solve it.

Comment: @hd I'm sorry, it was only a joke! I hope I can help you, but I agree with Pino that it's hard to understand what exactly is going wrong. Could you explain in more detail what is happening, and what you expected to happen?

Comment: @Spiny Norman: never mind ;) . as i said recently the problem was session issue on my web site and it is solved now.thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

author of the plugin here. Sorry I didn't catch this at the time, but obviously you found the issue - which is that you need to do `session_start();` at the top of your server script (both the simpleCaptcha.php script and the receiving script for the form).

Just wanted to add an answer in case others are looking for this same issue.